# Simple time constraint problem using C# and Microsoft Solver Foundation?

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I am trying to figure out the following simple problem in order to get acquainted with Solver Foundation.

I have 8 hours, 1 room and 3 teachers. Each teacher must hold 2 lectures 1 hour long each and each teacher must not hold 2 consecutive lectures. I am having trouble finding out how to model something that contains time in it. How can that be modeled into a mathematical equation?

I am not looking for a code block that does it, but rather an explanation or may be some resources that I can read.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I once was asked to solve a teacher scheduling problem for a whole school... I gave up. This looks interesting. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have 8 hours, and each lecture must be exactly 1 hour long, can’t you just model the 8 hours as “slots” that you put the teachers “into”? It seems equivalent to assigning people to cinema seats or similar (except of course that each teacher can have two time slots).